# Conflicting types during libpcap compilation

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-platform, libpcap

I'm trying to compile libpcap with cross compilator arm-linux-gcc. When I run 'make' I get an error:

```
./pcap-linux.c:254:14: conflicting types for socklen_t /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/unistd.h:275:21: note previous declaration of 'socklen_t'
```

I've also tried to compile it using common gcc but i have the same error. I work on ubuntu. How to resolve this problem

Answer (score 3):

`pcap-linux.c` makes an alias in next way:

```
#ifndef HAVE_SOCKLEN_T
typedef int     socklen_t;
#endif
```

You should pass `-DHAVE_SOCKLEN_T` to compiler or put

```
#define HAVE_SOCKLEN_T
```

to some header (usually it is done automatically by `configure` script or similar, that generates `config.h`).

Seems like you skipped build configuration step, so be ready to see another weird build errors.

Comment: thanks for your response. 
There is strange problem. When I define HAVE_SOCKLEN_T in the file or in makefile in DEFS I have still the same error

Comment: What does `configure --help` tell you?

Comment: unfortunatelly nothing